# sh pig command not found

Tags: sh

I setup a crontab that run a php script regularly. The php script runs a pig script using `exec()`.

However I get this error message:

> sh: pig: command not found

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run `pig` normally, from the command line? If so, run `whereis pig` to get the full path and use that in the crontab entry. If not, install it (using whatever method/package manager is normal on your OS.

Comment: yeah, i can run pig successfully, i do have full path to the pig, and i even try to run the php command directly, it works; further i tried to run the pig in sh 'sh pig -x local /full path/pigscript.pig' it worked, just the crontab job won't actually run the pig because i don't see any results generated. i setup the crontab using my account not root, would that cause a problem...?

Comment: So, just to be clear, the php program works as you expect when you run it directly? But the same exact php program fails when run by cron? I have to admit I'm rather stumped...what OS is this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your first issue is not able to find the pig path in the crontab since the error is "sh: pig: command not found". You might have a PATH variable in your local environment which is no longer present in your cron environment, try with absolute path to the pig script in your cron.